# Example of QRCode ZXing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, zxing

I need to create a qrreader with windows phone.

Xzing examples only print to video the qr string captured,
I need an example of how to understand if this string is a vcard and, consequently, save it in contact, or if it is a link and open it in the browser.

```
private void ScanPreviewBuffer()
    {

            try
            {
                _photoCamera.GetPreviewBufferY(_luminance.PreviewBufferY);
                var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(_luminance);
                var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
                var result = _reader.decode(binBitmap);
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => CheckQr(result.Text));
            }
            catch {  }
     }

    private void CheckQr(string qrString)
    {

        VibrateController vibrate = VibrateController.Default;
        vibrate.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

        MessageBox.Show(qrString);
        /* CONTROLS HERE */
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the documentation for encoding QR codes? that should tell you how to read it the encoded string

Comment: Yes but documentation/example only print to video the qrString decoded

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have to start by parsing the `qrString` content to get what you want, i think we'll both agree on that point ;)

So the main issues are :

- Determining formats (url or vcard)
- Parsing them (if needed)
- Using them to trigger wanted actions

**1.** About vCard

To determine if you `qrString` holds a vCard, maybe you could just try to match (with `string.Contains` or `string.StartsWith` methods) the vCard header which is `BEGIN:VCARD` and always seems to be the same from one version to another (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard)).

For Windows Phone 7, there's no builtin features to parse vCards, so you have to do it by yourself or you could try to use the [vCard library For Windows Phone](http://vcardlibrary.codeplex.com/). It would be used this way :

```
   byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(qrString);
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(byteArray)))
   {
      vCard card = new vCard(reader);
      // access here card.PropertyFromvCard to get the information you need
   }
```

There's not so much documentation about it, but [sources](http://vcardlibrary.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Thought.vCards.UnitTests/Samples/RfcAuthorTests.cs) are available on codeplex, so you'll probably find all the property names and samples you need.

For Windows Phone 8, the builtin [ContactInformation.ParseVcardAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.personalinformation.contactinformation.parsevcardasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method could help you to parse your `qrString` content (here is an official [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207024%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_SavingacontactfromaVCard))

Then you need to finally create your contact :

If you're developping your App on Windows Phone 7, there's no way to create a contact directly from your application. You need to use the "[save contact task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394013%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)" and pre-populate the fields you need. Here's an example :

```
SaveContactTask saveContactTask = new SaveContactTask();
saveContactTask.Completed += new EventHandler<SaveContactResult>(saveContactTask_Completed);
saveContactTask.FirstName = "John"; // card.PropertyFromvCard and so on...
saveContactTask.LastName = "Doe";
saveContactTask.MobilePhone = "2065550123";
saveContactTask.Show();
```

If you're developping on Windows Phone 8 (and it doesn't seem to be the case given your question tags), you can create a [Custom contact store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207034%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and write directly into it

**2.** About URLs

To know if you're dealing with an URL or not, i would advice you to follow suggestions coming with this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/161756/1014493). To make a long story short, here's the code you could use  or at least something similar :

```
static bool IsValidUrl(string qrString)
{
    Uri uri;
    return Uri.TryCreate(urlString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)
        && (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp
         || uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps
         || uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFtp
         || uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeMailto
            /*...*/);
}
```

And finally to open your URL into a web browser (if it is a valid one of course), you could use the [WebBrowser task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or embed a true WebBrowser into your application with the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and make good use of it.

Answer (score 0):

ZXing has a class called `ResultParser` with a static method `parseResult`.
The ResultParser supports some common content formats like vCard, vEvent, URL, etc.
It gives you as a result an instance of `AddressBookParsedResult` for vCard content back.

```
ParsedResult parsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(result);
```